# Using ERB(Rails) how do I get blocks of data to keep in their position?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building out a website using ERB with Bootstrap. I'm iterating through an array of my data (image, title, description, and body) using each_slice to put them into two per row. It works but...because the body of one piece of data extends further it pushes the next row from left column to right. So basically I want the following:

```
2, 3
4, 5
6, 7
8, 9
10
```

What happens is the following:

```
2, 3
   4
5, 6
   7
8, 9
  10
```

It happens because in the above the content for 2, 5, and 8 all have more height to them and forces the column to the right.

For the code I have:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <% @book.drop(1).each_slice(2) do |book, b| %>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10 col-sm-9">
            <%= image_tag book.book_image, class: 'wk-img' %>
                <p class="image-header wk-img-head paginaction-centered">
                    <%= book.title %>
                </p>
                <p class="image-text">
                    <%= book.description %>
                </p>
                <p class="image-text">
                    <%= book.body %>
                </p>


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10 col-sm-9">
            <% if b %>
                <%= image_tag b.book_image, class: 'wk-img' %>
                    <p class="image-header wk-img-head paginaction-centered">
                        <%= b.title %>
                    </p>
                    <p class="image-text">
                        <%= b.description %>
                    </p>
                    <p class="image-text">
                        <%= b.body %>
                    </p>
                    <% end %>
        </div>

        <% end %>
</div>
```

I've tried adding margin and padding to the larger sections (2, 5, and 8) but this does nothing. If I strip out the body of the text for each section...works perfectly. What am I doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping a `row` around each slice rather than around all of the items (or possibly in addition to depending on your desired design):

```
<div class="container">
  <% @book.drop(1).each_slice(2) do |book, b| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10 col-sm-9">
        <%= image_tag book.book_image, class: 'wk-img' %>
        <p class="image-header wk-img-head paginaction-centered">
          <%= book.title %>
        </p>
        <p class="image-text">
          <%= book.description %>
        </p>
        <p class="image-text">
          <%= book.body %>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10 col-sm-9">
        <% if b %>
          <%= image_tag b.book_image, class: 'wk-img' %>
          <p class="image-header wk-img-head paginaction-centered">
            <%= b.title %>
          </p>
          <p class="image-text">
            <%= b.description %>
          </p>
          <p class="image-text">
            <%= b.body %>
          </p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```